# GRUB not loading

Tags: linux, fedora, grub, mbr

I just installed Fedora 18 alongside a pre-existing windows 7 from a live-usb to a single 1TB hard disk with multiple partitions.

created all necessary partitions as recommended:

```
/     :40GB
/boot :200MB
/home :350GB
```

plus

```
BIOS BOOT of 1MB
```

The setup ended with a successful installation message but when I rebooted the GRUB didn't load. In fact the BIOS didn't show HDD in the boot order.

When I again booted using live-usb I saw that all the partitions were existing.

I tried reinstalling; the setup detected previous installation. I reinstalled with same partition sizes but again the boot failed.

I had read, recently, about installing Ubuntu in EFI mode, which specifies that:

1. There needs to be a EFI boot partition (Optional: with mount label /boot_efi).
2. It needs to be in the starting of the disk and should be FAT32

A windows EFI boot partition already exists. I thought I shouldnt mess up with this and created a separate BIOS BOOT partition for linux. I was not sure how to assign this as a EFI type partition. When I continued with the installation I saw that grub was installed and updated too.  But again linux failed to boot.

Comment: Is BIOS set to UEFI or legacy mode?

Comment: I shall verify.. most probably the UEFI mode.. 

Does the bios option have a mode setting? 

Also please let me know what difference does the mode make..

Comment: If I were you, I would disable UEFI if possible. Both Win7 and Fedora should work fine in legacy mode.

Comment: there is no particular option called disable UEFI in my BIOS. Does it have any alias ?

Comment: How many disks do you have and what partitions are on them? grub was installed to the first disk's mbr? /boot has the BOOT flag set?